# The & should follow type or in front of the parameter when using reference as function parameter?

Tags: c++

from what I know, if we use pointer or reference as a function parameter, it could written like this:
for reference:

```
void myfunction(int& x);
```

for pointer:

```
void myfunction(int *x);
```

but I recently see people written like this:

```
void myfunction(int &x);
```

I think it is still a reference, but if in general &x means getting the address of x, right? So, I am confused. Please help.

***Edit:*** please also help with the below code, not sure if the unexcepted result is causing by the way how I use reference:

what I want to achieve is using *myrecursive* to return the value if the size of *control_point* is 1, and using this value from another function

```
cv::Point2f myrecursive(const std::vector<cv::Point2f> &control_points, float t)
{
    if(control_points.size() != 1)
    {
        std::vector<cv::Point2f> temp_points;
        for (int i = 0; i < control_points.size() - 1; i++)
        {
            cv::Point2f t_point;
            //some code
            temp_points.push_back(t_point);
            
        }
        myrecursive(temp_points, t);
    }
    return control_points[0];
}



void myfunction(const std::vector<Point2f> &control_points, cv::Mat &window)
{
    for (double t - 0.0; t <= 1.0; t +=0.1)
    {
        cv::Point2f point = myrecursive(control_points, t);
    }
}
```

but if I print *point* in *myfunction*, it is always the first value of the original *control_points*
for example: the original *control_points* is ([0,1], [2,3]), after operation in *myrecursive*, assume it should return a point [5,6]. But in this line
`cv::Point2f point = myrecursive(control_points, t);` it alway return [0,1], why this happen?

Comment: `void myfunction(int& x);` and `void myfunction(int &x);` are the same. `void myfunction(int *x);` and `void myfunction(int* x);` are also the same as each other (though different from the reference versions). It's a relatively minor difference of preference. I tend to prefer sticking those qualifiers on the type, plenty of people like putting them on the variable, especially if they're used to C.

Comment: Be a rebel! `void myfunction(int & x);`

Comment: Whitespace between tokens is largely ignored by the compiler. `int& x`, `int &x`, `int         &         x`, they are all the same to the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but if in general &x means getting the address of x, right?

Outside a declaration, the `&` operator is the "address-of" operator. However, when declaring a variable, `&` is not an operator, but has a completely different meaning. It means that the declared variable is a reference.

The compiler doesn't care whether you write `int &x` or `int& x`. In both cases, it has the same meaning. Therefore, it is a matter of personal preference.

Personally, I prefer to write `int &x`, because writing `int& x` can be misleading, for example in the following situation:

`int& x, y;`

This formatting implies that both `x` and `y` are references, i.e. that the `&` refers to both `x` and `y`. However, according to the C++ syntax rules, the `&` only refers to `x`. Therefore, using this formatting style can lead to errors.

However, if you instead write

`int &x, y;`

then it is clear that the `&` only refers to `x` and not `y`, and it is immediately apparent that you must add a `&` if you want `y` to also be a reference.

On the other hand, when declaring only a single variable, writing `int& x` may be better, as it separates the name and the type of the variable.

Comment: Hi Andreas,  Thanks for your reply, and it helps a lot. But I got another problem, and not sure if that causing by my poor understanding with C++. I've edited my question already, please help.

Comment: @DannnnT: Regarding your follow-up question: In the function `myrecursive`, the recursive function call `myrecursive(temp_points, t);` doesn't have any observable effects, as you are discarding the return value and the function call does not have any side-effects, because it only modifies its own local variables. The line `return control_points[0];` will always return the first element of the vector. That is why `myfunction` is always getting the return value [0,1]. What are you trying to accomplish? I suggest that you create a new question with a [mre] and send me a link to it as a comment.

Comment: thanks for your time, and this is my new post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68486328/recursive-function-cannot-return-value-as-expected)